# How to download full directories off apache server via just a URL

Tags: apache2

I have searched all around and the only results I get are using wget or curl.

I would like to be able to download full directories being served on my apache server using just a URL. For example if I want to download the directory Contents, I would like to be able to do this: http://127.0.0.1/Contents. Instead, when I do this, I just get a page with all the files inside it instead of actually downloading the directory.

Is it because this is not possible? Or because i just need to configure it in apache2.conf ?

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out, in order to download a folder/directory from a URL, compress the folder into a .zip file or anything similar to .zip, then call it in the URL: http://127.0.0.1/yourfolder.zip